# clean url for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I convert this url

```
http://localhost/cms/index.php?page=register
```

to this

```
http://localhost/cms/page/register.html
```

Please help... I'm not that good in htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to make it work like you wish: :)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \/cms\/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page\=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ /cms/page/%1.html
```

Let me know in case of any issue... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cms/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) http://localhost/cms/index.php?page=$1-$2 [NC]
```